# Call TObject.GetInterface free object

Tags: delphi

I'm trying of execute a code like this:

```
IFoo = Interface
   procedure DoFoo;
end;

TFoo = class (TInterfaceObject, IFoo)
  .....
   procedure DoFoo;
end;

TFoo2 = class (TInterfaceObject)
  ......
end;

TGenClass = class
  class function DoSomething<T: class, cronstructor>: T;
end;

class function TGenClass.DoSomething<T>: T;
var Obj: T;
    Foo: IFoo;
begin
   Obj := T.Cretae;
   if Obj.GetInterfaceEntry(IFoo) <> nil then 
   begin
     Obj.GetInterface(IFoo, Foo);
     Foo.DoFoo;
   end;
   result := Obj;
end; 
......
var f: TFoo;
    f2: TFoo2; 
begin
  f:= TGenClass.DoSomeThing<TFoo>;
  f2:= TGenClass.DoSomeThing<TFoo2>;
  f2.free;
  f.free;
end;
```

When I execute this code, f.free raise a exception, because is already free, I suppose, because if I comment this lines

```
Obj.GetInterface(IFoo, Foo);
Foo.DoFoo;
```

it work.

¿How can execute IFoo interface without free object?

thk.

ADD:

Thanks all. I understand.

I tried to return IFoo with same result. My problem is that T could not be TInterfacedObject. The Java code I trying to convert is:

```
public  void dataIterate(int recNo, ResultSet data) throws SQLException {

    try {

        Constructor c = itemClass.getDeclaredConstructor();
        c.setAccessible(true);
        Object item = c.newInstance();
        if (item instanceof CustomInitialize) ((CustomInitialize)item).initialize(data);
        else {

            if (metadata == null ) metadata = data.getMetaData();
            for (int i=1; i<= metadata.getColumnCount(); i++)
                assignProperty(itemClass, item, "set"+metadata.getColumnName(i).toLowerCase(), data.getObject(i));

        }
        add((E)item);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new SQLDataException(ex);
    }
   ..........
```

Delphi  example code:

```
program Project4;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R*.res}

uses
   System.SysUtils,  System.Rtti;

type
  IFoo = Interface
     ['{F2D87AE6-1956-4B82-A28F-DC011C529849}']
     procedure DoFoo;
  end;

  TFoo = class (TInterfacedObject, IFoo)
  private
    FName: String;
  public
     procedure DoFoo;
     property Name: String Read FName write FName;
  end;

  TFoo2 = class (TObject)
  private
    FName: String;
  published
      property Name: String Read FName write FName;
  end;

TGenClass = class
  class function DoSomething<T: class, constructor>: T;
end;

class function TGenClass.DoSomething<T>: T;
var Obj: T;
    Foo: IFoo;
    Ap: TRttiProperty;
    Ctx: TRttiContext;
begin
   Obj := T.Create;
   if Obj.GetInterfaceEntry(IFoo) <> nil then
   begin
     Obj.GetInterface(IFoo, Foo);
     Foo.DoFoo;
   end;
   Ctx.GetType(TypeInfo(T)).GetProperty('Name').SetValue(TObject(Obj),'AName');
   result := Obj;
end;
{ TFoo }

procedure TFoo.DoFoo;
begin
  writeln('Foo executed.');
end;
var f: TFoo;
    f2:TFoo2;
begin
  try
    f:= TGenClass.DoSomeThing<TFoo>;
    f2:= TGenClass.DoSomeThing<TFoo2>;
    writeln(f2.Name);
    writeln(f.Name);   //<-- raise exception
    f.free;
    f2.Free;
    readln;

  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
```

Comment: Please don't post fake code. Please post your real code. Code that compiles. Use the clipboard to achieve this goal.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  And please post code that compiles.

Comment: I'm trying to convert a java code to delphi. In it, a object is create from a class reference, and if implement a interface, execute it.

Comment: Lifetime management is something you have to worry about in Delphi. Not so much in java with its garbage collection. Are you familiar with Delphi lifetime management? Are you familiar with Delphi rules for automatic reference counting of interfaces? Are you familiar with the protocols for TInterfacedObject?

Comment: It seems clear that the answer to these questions is "no" :). I understand that every time you assign a variable of type interface, a ref count is incremented, and when this varaible goes out of scope, this counter is decremeted. When there is not varaibles referencing the object, it's destroyed.

Comment: Your update is essentially the same code. It has the same problems mixing interfaces and object references. You need to decide either 1. Only use interface variables, or 2. Use an implementation of `IInterface` that does not manage lifetime. Do you know which you prefer?

Comment: Hmmm. As you see, java code use interface to query if class has a custom initializator. A class can or not implement it. Maybe my solution is to use rtti to query if class have a method called initialize with the required params.Anyway, thank you very much for their answers. You've helped me a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take a look at this code:

```
class function TGenClass.DoSomething<T>: T;
var Obj: T;
    Foo: IFoo;
begin
   Obj := T.Create;
   if Obj.GetInterfaceEntry(IFoo) <> nil then 
   begin
     Obj.GetInterface(IFoo, Foo);
     Foo.DoFoo;
   end;
   result := Obj;
end;
```

After `Obj := T.Create`, the object has a reference count of zero, because no interface variable has yet referenced it. Then you call `GetInterface` and take an interface reference in `Foo`. So the object now has a reference count of 1. Then the function returns and `Foo` goes out of scope. This reduces the reference count to 0 and so the object is freed.

When you use `TInterfacedObject`, you must always hold an interface variable. So that the reference counting can manage the object's life. In this case you have mixed object references and interface variables and that invariably leads to pain and anguish.

I can't really advise you on what your code should look like because I don't know what your problem is. All I have attempted to do is to explain the behaviour for you. Perhaps  `DoSomething` should be returning `IFoo` rather than `T`. Or perhaps you need to stop using reference counted lifetime management. Very hard to be sure from here.